# If I made a mistake and posted the wrong answer, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion

Okay, this is my first question on Meta Stack Overflow, so if I'm posting this in the wrong way then sorry.

Let's say that I read a question and I posted what I thought was the correct answer. I'm all happy that I've answered another person's question and helped them out, but it turns out that my answer was really off topic and not what they were looking for, it gets downvotes and offensive comments and all that stuff. Should I delete that post?

Now, I'm really not sure. That's why I asked you guys for an opinion. Let's consider the pros and cons:

#### Pros:

- I could've misread the person's question and confused everyone, so it's good that I delete it.
- All those down votes for a mistake? It's better to delete it.
- People could've thought it was spam and reported me! leaving me helpless in the world of programming.

#### Cons:

- Although it may not have been the correct answer, someone could have learnt something from my mistake.
- Some people might accept that I've made a mistake and given me constructive criticism.

A long first post, I know. I'd love to hear someone else's opinion on the topic.

Comment: If you know that your answer is off-topic, edit it and improve it. Improving a post is always good.

Comment: And if the question can be improved (off-topic answers are often associated with unclear questions), edit the question too by suggesting an edit. Like I edited your question..

Comment: Protip: it's not really a good idea to end a post with "Bye!"

Comment: As @BoltClock said, bye is not good. Why did you revert the edit and add bye again?

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: I didn't.

Comment: You did (in Revision 3), thanks for removing the bye in rev 4